# Trying to make collision detection work using immovable objects in p5.play

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, p5.js

I'm trying to work out a practice problem for making a game from https://pdm.lsupathways.org/2_graphics/3_bugsquish/2_lesson_2/sprite-interactivity-1/ where they ask you to create long thin rectangle sprites as a way to create borders that can keep the movable player sprite within the screen. The idea is that the player sprite will hit the "walls" and the wall will act as the barrier keeping it from going out the screen.

However I can't seem to figure out the exact way to make the sprite's response to collision detection work right as the wall seems to attach itself to the player sprite (?) whenever it is collided with instead of staying put like it is meant to.

```
let walls;

let ball, player, wall1, wall2, wall3, wall4;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  
  
  
  ball = createSprite(300, 300, 20,20);
  ball.shapeColor = [0,0,0];
  
  player = createSprite(50, 300, 25, 75);
  player.shapeColor = [20, 200, 20];
  
  walls = new Group();
  
  wall1 = createSprite(width/2, 0, width, 10);
  
  wall2 = createSprite(0, height/2, 10, height);
  
  wall3 = createSprite(width/2, height, width, 10);
  
  wall4 = createSprite(width, height/2, 10, height);
  
  walls.add(wall1)
  walls.add(wall2)
  walls.add(wall3)
  walls.add(wall4)
 
  walls.immovable = true;
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
 drawSprites();
  
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
    player.setSpeed(10, 180);
  } else if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
    player.setSpeed(10, 0);
  } else if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) {
    player.setSpeed(10, 270);
  } else if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {
    player.setSpeed(10, 90);
  }
  player.bounce(ball)
  ball.collide(walls)
  player.bounce(walls)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at this library https://github.com/bmoren/p5.collide2D

it has a lot of 2d collision functions. For your use, you're prob looking for collideRectRect.